# Have to paste in console twice in order to get results? Also saying undefined is not a function?

Tags: jquery

In the following code, if I paste it in console, I get the error `SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '[object HTMLDocument]' is not a valid selector.`

If I ignore the error and paste it again before refreshing the browser, the code goes through, returning the error `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Please help, this is my code, thanks!

Also please note you have to be on the page to run it, which I am

```
(function(d,s){s=d.createElement('script');s.src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js';(d.head||d.documentElement).appendChild(s)})(document);
$(document).ready(function() {
var id = 158066137;
var link = 'http://api.roblox.com/marketplace/productinfo?assetId=' + id;
setInterval(function() {
    $.get(link, function(data) {
        var value = data;
        var isRobloxMade = value.indexOf('"Creator":{"Id":1,"Name":"ROBLOX"}');
        if (isRobloxMade >= 0) {
            console.log(value);
        }
    });
}, 10);
});
```

Comment: Do you get the same error if it is not pasted in the console, but instead used in a .js file? Have you tried using a newer version of jQuery, instead of 1.8.3?

Comment: Yes and yes to both questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, to my knowledge it's not possible to load jQuery asynchronously without a helper library such as [jQi](http://www.yterium.net/jQl-an-asynchronous-jQuery-Loader). The specific error that you're seeing is because some browsers have mapped `$` to `document.querySelectorAll` and thus expect only a CSS selector.

Secondly, jQuery automatically turns the JSON response into an object that doesn't have the `.indexOf()` method. Your code should therefore be:

```
if (data.Creator.Id == 1 && data.Creator.Name == 'ROBLOX') {
    console.log(data);
}
```

Comment: The code provided works, thanks, but I still get the first error

Comment: @Sam My answer already touches on the subject of loading jQuery asynchronously; are you using jQI?

Comment: No idea what that is, sorry

Comment: @Sam Then you're probably not using it right and that would be a different question; why can't you just load jQuery at the end of your document?

Comment: I'm running this in console; it isn't a file.

Comment: @Sam Well, then run the first statement first ... wait .. then run the second portion.